# Are there decent, free malware solutions for Linux?

Tags: linux, malware, scanner

I looked around for an antivirus on Linux (Arch) or malware scanner, bumped on ClamAV and I don't even remember if I got it to work so fair to say it didn't make the cut at the moment in time.

Are there free, good AVs for Linux?

I find people saying there are no viruses for Linux, that's why there are no AVs, but I find it hard to believe. One can write malware code for any system.

I think it's curious, an ecosystem like Linux with deep roots in open source, does not have an open source malware solution seemingly.

Comment: Seems to be better suitable for the [Softwarerecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) community.

Comment: Can - but writing malware for Linux requires either creating code that can run on every Linux distro; or separate code for every distro and even version; or targeting something like a database engine which isn't even installed on majority of the Linux systems... and still there's the question of versions. So writing effective malware that can spread widely the same way Win threats can is much more demanding operation. Like in any ecosystem, homogenity requires pretty strong crutches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[maldet](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/linux-malware-detect/) is the best solution for malware detection on Linux. It's using it's own signature database, and can use ClamAV as an engine. I've used it for many years and it has always detected all kinds of malware on production systems.